# With $A$ and $B$ subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$, is $A \subset B \implies A^\perp \subset B^\perp$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$.

Consider the following proposition:
$$A \subset B \implies A^\perp \subset B^\perp\qquad (1)$$

I am aware that the following is true:
$$A \subset B \implies B^\perp \subset A^\perp\qquad (2)$$

However, I attempted to "prove" $(1)$ as follows:

> To prove $A^\perp \subset B^\perp$, let us show that $$\forall y \in
> A^\perp, y \in B^\perp$$
> If $y \in A^\perp$, then: $$\forall x \in A, \langle x,y \rangle = 0$$
> Because $A \subset B$ is true, meaning, $$\forall x \in A, x \in B$$ it follows that $$\forall x \in B, \langle x, y \rangle = 0$$i.e. $$y \in B^\perp$$

I am convinced that this proof is flawed since I haven't come across $(1)$ in any textbook, instead, proposition $(2)$ always showed up. Any indications as to what went wrong in the above proof is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown that $\forall x\in B,\langle x,y\rangle=0$; you have shown that this is true only for some portion of $x\in B$, namely the $x$ also in $A$. That's the flaw.

Comment: $A=\{0\}, B=H$ is an obvious counter-example.

Comment: If everything in $A$ is in $B$ (i.e., $A\subseteq B$,) then anything which is orthogonal to everything in $B$ is obviously orthogonal to everything in $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in this proof is the step that starts "it follows that...". The reason is that there could be $z \in B$ such that $z \not \in A$ and then you can't say anything about $\langle z, y \rangle$.

What you have written is actually almost a proof of $(2)$ [with $A$ and $B$ swapped]. You just had to write instead
"because $B \subset A$ is true, meaning $\forall x \in B, x \in A$, it follows that $\forall x \in B, \langle x,y \rangle = 0$..."